# Get instance of ApiController class from a URL directly

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I am looking for a way to call the appropriate method (get, post etc.) on an ApiController class based on the URL and request type etc.  without making a http request.

Background: We have an API application with numerous controllers that needs to also  accept requests from a remote server.  Due to restrictions I cannot control there is no way to open ports between the two servers to allow the remote server to make the request directly so we decided to forward the data using websockets (SignalR).  I can send (within reason) whatever information is required.

I have tried the below:

```
HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage();
var bld = new UriBuilder
{
    Port = 123,
    Path = "api/v1/search",
    Query = "query=search_string"
};
request.RequestUri = bld.Uri;

var httpCfg = AppConfiguration.Get().HttpConfig; //this is the same config that UseWebApi was called with and contains the routes. 
var route = httpCfg.Routes.GetRouteData(request);
var controllerSelector = new DefaultHttpControllerSelector(httpCfg);

var descriptor = controllerSelector.SelectController(request);
```

route contains the controller name (search) but the call to SelectController throws an exception with a 404 response in it (I presume this indicates I am missing something from the fake request).  The same URI works when sent as a direct http request so the routes do work as best I can tell.

Is there a better way to do this, or if not what am I missing from the request that is causing the 404?

Comment: Hi! Welcome to stack overflow, if your question does not attract answers, check out https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask to get good tips on how to get improve it ;)

Comment: Is this code written in the WebAPI itself?

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya, It is in the same application yes, but not within a controller class or similar if that is what you mean.